# SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER When using fiddler to detect https?

Tags: fiddler

They said I go to tools options descrypt https traffic.

However, I get a certificate warning.

What should I do?
[image]

This is what I see

https://www.telerik.com/forums/untrusted-connection I tried solution here and it doesn't work. Action. Reset. Still the same problem. Should I restart the computer or what?

Comment: You should learn about MITM attacks, because you are actually performing one and HTTPS is designed to detect these as above.  If you want to allow this behaviour you need to correctly add not the sites certificate, but the certificate authorities cert, and be aware that anything signed by that ca cert will then be accepted by the browser as OK.

Comment: How exactly do I do so? Yes, I am aware I am committing a MITM attack on my own self. Any other better ways to get those data from Fiddler.